# Is it possible to let to GCP choose availability zone for a new VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

During a new VM launch,  gcloud allows you to choose region+zone, for instance, '--zone=us-central1-a'.
Occasionally, my 'gcloud compute instances create' fails with the following error 'code: ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS'.  I.e. chosen zone doesn't have enough capacity for my instance type. It will be nice to have the ability to ask GCP to launch a new VM in a certain region, in any availability zone (as we have in another cloud provider). But I couldn't find such a feature.
Update: I'm using these VMs in my CI on-demand workflows (with Tesla T4 GPU, custom type with 8,12,24 CPUs, in europe-west4-a).

Comment: For a single VM, not, it's not possible; For production purpose, you can hack the regional managed instance group by defining the distribution pattern to ANY or BALANCED https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/regional-mig-distribution-shape#comparison_of_shapes

Answer (score 3):

[ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability) is one of the common resource errors that you might encounter when you request new Compute Engine resources or create new reservations. Refer to this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-resource-availability) to resolve these errors and  Unfortunately GCP doesn't have this feature to ask gcp to launch a new VM in a certain region, in any [availability zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) rather than we need to check manually availability zones and need to deploy.

In order to avoid this kind of resource errors you can create [Compute Engine reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview) ahead of when you need the resources. Reservations help ensure that resources are available when you need them.

As per this [Reservations doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview),

> With reservations, 95% of VMs start in less than 120 seconds. Each
> reservation provides assurance for one or more VMs with the same
> properties. After you create a reservation, the reserved resources are
> available immediately and remain available until you delete the
> reservation. Similarly, you begin paying for the reserved resources
> immediately, and, when you no longer need a reservation, you can
> delete the reservation to stop incurring charges for it. While a VM is
> consuming a reservation, it does not incur separate charges.

As, this is also a valid request and you can raise a feature request at [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) report with the description of your issue . This Issue Tracker is a forum for end users to report bugs and request features to improve google cloud products. Product engineering from Google will work on this implementation.

Comment: Many thanks!
I'm using these VMs in my CI on-demand workflows, so using reservation is not relevant. 
But I definitely will add a feature request.

Comment: @VitalyKarasikDevOps - that is an important detail. Add that to your question. Because smaller instance sizes are in high demand, for CI/CD, I deploy larger instance sizes. Are you launching small instances? Using reservations is a good idea as well.

Comment: @JohnHanley - thank you, good point, I updated my question.
>  smaller instance sizes are in high demand
I'm using  custom-12-24576 and custom-24-98304 , tried custom-8-24576 (all of them with GPU) - it happens with all of them from time to time. 
I'm using europe-west4-a, I suspect there is no way to know which zone is more capable.

Comment: @VitalyKarasikDevOps - I think GPU availability is the issue.